# jquery: Change url and bring back on form condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Original post got a whole lot of people excited and no constructive comments at all. 2nd try.

I do realize that it's javascript, and it can easily be hacked

The whole idea is to change url on page load, and bring back the original one if form entery is correct. 
Ran into problem where part of the script that is supposed to bring back original href value doesn't allow it to be changed in the very beginning.

here is the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".link_imagelibrary").each(function(){
  this.href = this.href.replace('http://whatevs.com/files/pass', '#');
});



 $(".imglogin").click(function () {
console.log('working')
var password = "111";
 if ($("#imgpass").val() != password) {
    alert("Wrong Password!");
  $('#imgpass').val('');
 } else {       

 $(".link_imagelibrary").addClass(".imgdownload");
  $("div.center a").removeClass("link_imagelibrary");
  $(".imgdownload").each(function(){
  this.href = this.href.replace('#', 'http://whatevs.com/files/pass');
}
});   
});
```

Where is my mistake? Thanks!

Comment: You realize people can see your javascript right... they could undo this, or just turn off javascript to access your links.

Comment: What type of element is `.imglogin`? Also, what is happening? Are you getting any js console errors? Are the links getting replaced with "#" to begin with? Is the click on `.imglogin` doing anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try replace the class ".link_imagelibrary" and ".imgdownload", for id elemment

Comment: can't do it to .link_imagelibrary. it's assigned by cms

Comment: try manipulate with attribute "data" for example: data-success="true" for download the image

Comment: i'm as noob as they come in JC. Could you expand your answer a little bit more plz?

Answer (score 0):

i think you may like to try this js lib : https://github.com/mshang/base64-js (or you can find similar in web)
replace or add encoded links at beginning and when user clicks verify login if user logged in decode the link and redirect to that link or do what you want to do.

eg:

```
var xyz = base64;
xyz.encode("http://whatevs.com/files/pass");
```

then after user logged in:

```
xyz,decode("aHR0cDovL3doYXRldnMuY29tL2ZpbGVzL3Bhc3M=");
//returns http://whatevs.com/files/pass
```